# Scrape yellowpages.com

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape yellowpages.com using VBA using the following code but no data is getting recorded

```
For Each ele In .document.all
Select Case ele.tagname
Case Results 
RowCount = RowCount + 1 
Case "Name" 
sht.Range("A" & RowCount)=ele.innerText
Case "Adress" 
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "Email" 
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
End 
Select Next ele 
End With
```

The results are just blank no error

Answer (score 0):

`Case Results` is wrong unless you have a variable called Results. You probably want `Case "Results"` instead

Not sure if it's just your formatting here that is wrong but:

```
End
Select Next ele
```

should be

```
End Select
Next ele
```